# Shapefile for same region but they are not overlapping

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, shapefile

i have two shapefile for same region but they are not overlapping with each other. one data set is admin boundaries which i have purchased form the survey of India and other data set is ward boundaries of the cities which i have downloaded form the government website. i have projected the ward boundaries in same projection system as the admin boundaries but still its not overlapping. what i should do.??

**Admin boundaries details:**
Projected Coordinate System:    LCC_WGS84
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  4000000.00000000
False_Northing: 4000000.00000000
Central_Meridian:   80.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    12.47294400
Standard_Parallel_2:    35.17280600
Scale_Factor:   1.00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 24.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

Comment: How did you *project to the same projection system*? It sounds like you've defined rather than projected. What were the original spatial references for the data as purchased/downloaded?

Comment: the ward boundaries were undefined, so no spatial reference. Coordinate System: <Undefined>

Comment: spatial reference of the admin boundary : PROJCS["LCC_WGS84",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",4000000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",4000000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",80.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",12.472944],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",35.172806],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",24.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: Spatial reference of the ward boundary is: PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_43N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",75.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: Have you assigned WGS84 Zone 43 North to your admin boundaries? Hint: use Define Projection http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000077000000 to assert the correct values where there are currently none. Both are based on the WGS84 datum so they should align no problem unless either one or both of those asserted spatial references is wrong, the maps' spatial reference is undefined or you don't have *project on the fly* enabled.